# Create appx file for Raspberry pi2 on Windows IOT Core?

Tags: raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I've got a Windows Universal app that I want to package and deploy to Windows IOT Core  running on a Raspberry Pi2. I can get the code to deploy from Visual Studio, but i want to hand off the app to someone else and have them install without  I was expecting a way to deploy via the web interface since there is a place to upload an appx file, but i can't figure out any way to get that built up. Is it possible w/o Visual Studio?
Thanks,
   Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1: Build**
Create an app package from Visual Studio:

1. Right click your project
2. Choose Store...Create App Packages
3. Choose "No" for creating package to upload to Windows Store
   [image: Create Your Packages]
4. On the next step, select "Never" for "Generate app bundle" and make sure "ARM" is checked.
   [image: Select and Configure Packages]
5. Click Create.  The Raspberry Pi compatible build will be in ".\AppPackages\XX_ARM_XX" folder.
   [image: Package folder]

**Step 2: Install**
Install the app on the Raspberry Pi:

1. Open the "Windows Device Portal" website
2. Choose "Apps" from the side menu
3. Upload the *.appx and *.cer files from the build folder

You can learn more here:
[Packaging UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
[Windows Device Portal](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/tools/DevicePortal.htm) (scroll down to Apps section)